# Pricing Rules Runs Successfully, but Discount does not seem to apply

Tags: catalog-price-rules

I'm having an issue currently where we have Daily Deals running on the site, where two products will be selected on a daily basis for a 50% discount. When calling $_product->getFinalPrice(); no discounts appear to be actually on the item. The item appears at full price on the daily deal page and in the cart.

Where would I check this, and how does Magento determine if there's a discount on the item? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is your cron running? There is a process that runs at 3am to recalculate pricing rules.
Or try re-indexing price rules manually.

Comment: We have been logging the cron jobs and they appear to be running successfully.  Also re-indexing happens hourly in my crontab.  The item changes, but only sometimes shows the discount.